# Lazyloading images blocked by external slow loading scripts

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, lazy-loading

I have a jquery lazy load script and some produxt images are using lazy load.

I also have some external scripts like google analytics, fb pixel, google conversion tracking etc. these scripts are async, yet the when one of them loads slower the lazy load waits for the “load” event and does not start to load the images until the scripts finish loading… which is stupid, the whole point of async js is not to block page rendering…

Here is a screenshot and a video :

https://share.getcloudapp.com/yAu0bmW6

https://watch.screencastify.com/v/WcKAo5A5jsPyFWd8eQiJ

Any idea what i can do to make lazy load ignore the async scripts?

Comment: Can you post your code that hadnles the lazy loading?

Comment: I am using this code:  http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/
    $(function() {
        $('.lazy').lazy();
    });

Comment: Why not use [native lazy loading?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading)  `<img src="image.jpg" alt="..." loading="lazy">`

Comment: Yes, seems this works better :) Thanks!

Comment: But still, i am curios how would you be able to fix the lazy js situation? Because i also have some js code that executes on load, and has the same problem...